# R function to adjust column type to date format

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, format

I have a decent-sized dataset converted from csv. files that includes a date column. I need to convert this column from character type to date format. I have tried using `parse_date` function but it keeps returning an error:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 file1 <- read_csv(file1, na = "-", skip = 7)

 file1$Date <- parse_date(file1$Date, format ="%Y-%B-%d")

Warning: 31 parsing failures.
```

or..

```
Error in parse_vector(x, col_date(format), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
 is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

How do I fix this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT::

```
 Date       `Minimum temper~ `Maximum temper~ `Rainfall (mm)` 
 <date>                <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            
       
 1 NA                      7.6             15.4             0   NA                            
 2 NA                     -3.8             14.3             0   NA                              
 3 NA                     -3.6             19.5             0   NA                            
 4 NA                      3.7             12.8            13.8 NA                             
 5 NA                     -1               15               0   NA                           
 6 NA                      1.2             13.7             0   NA                            
 # ... with 15 more variables: `Direction of maximum wind gust` <chr> etc..
```

Original file1

```
  Date  `Minimum temper~ `Maximum temper~ `Rainfall (mm)` 
   <chr>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            
  1 1/08~              7.6             15.4             0                
  2 2/08~             -3.8             14.3             0                
  3 3/08~             -3.6             19.5             0               
  4 4/08~              3.7             12.8            13.8              
  5 5/08~             -1               15               0                 
  6 6/08~              1.2             13.7             0              
      # ... with 15 more variables:
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for the advice. Have now edited my original question to include the first few lines of data.

Comment: The following are the values in the date column `[1] "1/08/2018"  "2/08/2018"  "3/08/2018"  "4/08/2018"  "5/08/2018"  "6/08/2018"  "7/08/2018" 
 [8] "8/08/2018"  "9/08/2018"  "10/08/2018" "11/08/2018" "12/08/2018" "13/08/2018" "14/08/2018"
[15] "15/08/2018" "16/08/2018" "17/08/2018" "18/08/2018" "19/08/2018" "20/08/2018" "21/08/2018"
[22] "22/08/2018" "23/08/2018" "24/08/2018" "25/08/2018" "26/08/2018" "27/08/2018" "28/08/2018"
[29] "29/08/2018" "30/08/2018" "31/08/2018"`

Comment: Thanks for your above suggestion but I received the following message: `Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.`  With all values returning NA:   `file1$Date <- lubridate::ymd(file1$Date)
> file1$Date
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[31] NA`

Comment: yes, sorry you need to use `dmy` instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as.Date` with correct format :

```
file1$Date <- as.Date(file1$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Or with `lubridate` :

```
file1$Date <- lubridate::dmy(file1$Date)
```

Comment: @josie You should ask that as a new question so that each post focusses on only one problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
file1$Date <- anydate(file1$Date)
```